# Why two plurals in Sim Shalom?

Tags: prayer-book

The bracha sim shalom, at the end of the amida, has two plural terms: aleinu v'al kol yisrael.

The other brachot in the amida have only one plural term (e.g. bareich aleinu).

Are the two plural terms in Sim Shalom just redundant with no meaning or import, or what do they mean and what is the import?

Comment: Many genizah fragments omit עלינו (and some omit both).